# How can I chain my form with just one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a form with many select tags and in every select tag another select will open, and in this select another and another, another and another until the end of the form.

I have this now http://jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/1/, but It's not generic, and I'll need to call this function in every select.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.select').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $('.divR1').show();
            $('.divR2').hide();

        }else if($(this).val() == "2"){
            $('.divR2').show();
            $('.divR1').hide();
        }

        else {
            $('.divR1').hide();
            $('.divR2').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="div1">
    <select class="select" autocomplete="off">
        <option value="#" checked>Escolha</option>
        <option value="1">Sim</option>
        <option value="2">Não</option>
    </select>

    <div class="divR1" style="display:none">
        1
        <select autocomplete="off">
            <option value="#" checked>Escolha</option>
            <option value="1">Sim</option>
            <option value="2">Não</option>
        </select>   
    </div>

    <div class="divR2" style="display:none">
        2
        <select autocomplete="off">
            <option value="#" checked>Escolha</option>
            <option value="1"></option>
            <option value="2"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/5/

```
$(function () {
    $(".select").change(function () {
        var next = $('option', this).filter(':selected').attr('next');
        $($(this).attr('hide')).hide();
        if (next != undefined) {
            $(next).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Same problem. If I try to add a new div called id="div2" the second select can change the first one. Like this one jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/8

Comment: Look carefully at html part http://jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/5/ Each div have its own class, each select have attribute "hide" (selector of elements that should be hidden if nothing selected) and each option have attribute "next" (selector of element that should be shown when this option selected).

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function() {
    $( ".select" ).change( function() {
       var id = $( this ).val();
       $( ".selectDiv" ).hide();
       $( ".divR" + id ).show();
    });
});
```

I added "selectDiv" class to all your dependent divs ; also, "divR" should be an ID ant not a class, if it is unique ;)

EDIT [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBQZr/)

Comment: Consider using jquery next() function, this way you can do without "id" referencing. $(this).parent('div').next('div').find('select')

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle link please?

Comment: Look what happen if I try to add another div with the same classes.
http://jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/8/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did not clearly define end of form so, here is one example which keeps going till you want it to :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SZ5n/6/)

```
$(function () {
    $('select').change(handler);
});

function handler() {
    var x = $(this);
    if (x.val() != '#') {
        var div = $('<div>').append(x.val());
        x.parent().append(div);
        var select = $('<select>')
            .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
            .change(handler)
            .append($('<option>').attr('value', '#').append('Escolha'))
            .append($('<option>').attr('value', '1').append('Sim'))
            .append($('<option>').attr('value', '2').append('Não'));
        div.append(select);
    } else {
        x.siblings().remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but each select tag can't create more than one new select. Each select must show just the selected option. 

Example:
First Select : Yes Or Not?
Ans: Not (New div + new select with Yes or not)

Comment: In this case, if I change the option from 'Sim' to 'Não' both options continue in show mode, I need that only the options selected in the path are shown. And if the option selected change in any time, a new div with another select or form must overwrite the actual div.